# Which lines do change after a sync in /proc/meminfo ?

Tags: proc, synchronization

I was taught, that the sync command writes the data stored within the cache of the RAM onto hard-disk, this release should be displayed in /proc/meminfo. However when I cat /proc/meminfo before and after a sync I can not see any difference, the line with buffers and cage stays the same.

Where can I actually see the change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at [this answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48245/82289).

You can run this command to watch an interractive display of the changes:

```
watch grep -e Dirty: -e Writeback: /proc/meminfo
```