# How to get physical (synced) disk usage, ignoring system cache?

Tags: disk-usage, cache

I'm using `du` to continuously monitor the amount of data written to USB drives that I'm duplicating.

I compare disk usage of source and target drives and display copying progress to the user.

The problem is that `du` reports 100% data present on the target drive, even though I see lots of data is still in the system cache, the drive's LED is blinking, and the drives are not ready to be removed.

I run `rsync`, `sync` and `umount` in sequence to ensure the data is really there before letting the user remove the target drive. I can't monitor the `sync` progress however. So the user will see 100% long before the drives are really synced.

I'd love to be able to monitor the "real" copying progress, as it's what really matters - there's no use to see `rsync` complete copying 1 GB file in 25 seconds, while I'll have to wait another 5 minutes while `sync` flushes that to drive (I'm exaggerating, but you get the idea).

This is how I monitor `rsync` progress in a loop for each drive:

```
PROGRESS="$(echo "$(du -s "/MEDIA/TARGET" 2>/dev/null  | cut -f 1) / $(du -s "/MEDIA/SOURCE" 2>/dev/null | cut -f 1) " | bc -l)"
```

`$PROGRESS` is a float between 0 and 1, indicating the ratio between source drive usage and target drive usage.

**How can I modify this so it'll consider only data that is already synced to drive, and not just waiting in system cache?**

**Edit:**

I found that `dd` can perform writes omitting the system cache. I made a test and indeed copying a file this way makes `du` report actual values, and my progress indications would finally be accurate:

```
dd if=/media/SOURCE/file of=/media/TARGET/file bs=4M oflag=direct
```

This uses the read cache, but disabled the write cache, making the proress easier to track, without performing excessive reads. The problem is, to use `dd` instead of `rsync` I need to manually recreate the directory structure. I don't need to take care of the file attributes or modification dates.

I guess I could use a combination of `find`, `mkdir` and `dd` to first recreate the directory tree and then copy the files one by one. I wonder - if there are any downsides to this approach?

Comment: You can in fact monitor `sync` [progress](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48245/111103).

Comment: Yes, but only as a summary for all drives present in the system - I'd like to be able to do this for each individual block device.

Comment: `atop` and `iostat` give I/O activity by block device, so I always assumed this ignores internal caches and only measures "real" I/O.

Comment: Even if `atop` and `iotop` gave physical write and read speeds - they a re still just speeds, I need to know the amount of data that has been written, I can calculate xfer speed later if I need it.

For a cached write atop reports a steady write speed of around 9.7 MB/s. That makes me think it is physical write speed, not the caching speed (as I can see there's several hundreds of  MB in the cache still (that the system normally considers as already written - which is not true).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best way to handle this is to use **direct file output**. This way `du` readings will be much more accurate.

Unfortunately only `dd` allows that, so we need to workaround two problems:

1. `dd` doesn't know what to do with directories
2. `dd` can only copy one file at a time

First let's define input and output directories:

```
SOURCE="/media/source-dir"
TARGET="/media/target-dir"
```

Now let's `cd` into the source directory so `find` will report relative directories we can easily manipulate:

```
cd "$SOURCE"
```

Duplicate the directory tree from `$SOURCE` to `$TARGET`

```
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p "$TARGET{}" \;
```

Duplicate files from `$SOURCE` to `$TARGET` omitting write cache (but utilising read cache!)

```
find . -type f -exec dd if={} of="$TARGET{}" bs=8M oflag=direct \;
```

This won't preserve file modification times, ownership and other attributes - but for me that's ok.