sync hangs and cannot be killed
OS is Debian 12.
I copied some data to a usb drive, then ran the sync command to ensure I could remove it safely. The sync command then appeared to be stuck.
After waiting for half an hour, I tried attaching strace, which showed no changing output.
I cannot kill the sync, even with kill -9. ps shows the sync command in the "D" state.
How do I get the sync command to exit without rebooting? What is wrong with sync? Is it just not used anymore? I've never been able to run it before without something like this happening.
Can I just leave the sync stuck in "D" for now? Will it interfere with my normal desktop operation? I really do not want to reboot.

Well, AFAIK the program really just calls a system call, which is why you can't stop it. Sounds like your USB drive is problematic. You may want to check iostat and/or dmesg, or consider unplugging the drive.

It would be nice if you told us how much data you are copying?

There is no issue with the usb drive. I had the same issue happen a few weeks ago with a microsd card. Amount of data copied is 500 mb.

You can watch the progress of a sync operation in various different ways - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48235/can-i-watch-the-progress-of-a-sync-operation That will help you figure out if it has really hung or is just still busy.
